# How to determine memory size via C code

Tags: c

Is it possible to get the memory size ( i.e., RAM) via C code? For instance, we can generate a directory using `system("mkdir -p /path/")` where `mkdir` is actually a unix command. Can I do something similar to get the memory size assuming I am on linux system?

Thank you

Comment: memory size of what?

Comment: @user5250644 I mean RAM

Comment: Fun but impractical solution: binary search the available memory with `malloc`

Comment: More information about what you are trying to accomplish would be helpful. If you want to know about resource usage on POSIX systems (like Linux), you can use [`getrlimit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html). You can use `RLIMIT_AS` to find the maximum size of memory available to a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use free

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8093896     3657260     2163392       68360     2273244     4109636
Swap:      27733868     1045556    26688312
```

In a program:

```
/* mem.c */
int main()
{
  system("free");
}
```

And as a proof of concept:

```
$ gcc mem.c
$ ./a.out
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8093896     3692808     2122384       68360     2278704     4074036
Swap:      27733868     1045544    26688324
```

Comment: Thanks. how do I write that in C? `system("free")`?

Comment: That mac os may be the problem. It works for me in Debian.

Comment: Is it possible to only get (total) from `free` without other parameters ?

Comment: Nope, sorry. You'll have to format the output. However, one start can be `free | head -2 | tail -1` That will give you that particular line. Always something. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux systems there is `sysinfo()`:

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sysinfo info;
    sysinfo(&info);

    // use info.totalram, info.freeram, etc
    printf("%lu bytes\n", info.totalram);

    return 0;
}
```

Check you man page on `sysinfo(2)` to know all the details of the struct.